# jQuery Ajax browser freezes in dom manipulation

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a PHP script that serves a table in HTML format. I'm using jQuery ajax to call that script, show an animation image and then load the html table result in the page. The issue I'm facing is that in FireFox when the AJAX call is done the page freezes and the animation too before the table is loaded. In Chrome the image freezes only and the browser is still responding. In IE9 I see no table loaded and the image is frozen too but not the browser.

Is there anyway or any approche to avoid the browsers and the animations from freezing?

the code I'm using in javascript is :

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#btn").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
              cache:false,
              url: 'file.php',
              dataType: 'html',
              beforeSend: function(){
                $("#ajax").append('<div><img src ="ajax-loader-bar.gif" style="margin-top: 5%;"/></br><b>Processing your file, please wait...</b></div>');
              },
              success:function(data){
                $("#myTable").html(data);
              },
              error: function(data){
              },
              complete: function(resultat, statut){
                $("#ajax").html("");
              }
        }); 
     });
  });
  </script>
```

The HTML code is :

```
<body>
  <div>
   <input id="btn" type="button" value="Create table">
   <div id="ajax"></div>
   <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
   </table> 
  </div>
</body>
```

And the PHP returns a result like this :

```
<thead><tr><th><input id='chk-all' type='checkbox'></th><th>Column 1</th><th>Column 2</th><th>Column 3</th><th>Column 4</th><th>Column 5</th><th>Column 6</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr id='row_0'><td><input class='input_chk' id='chkrow_0' type='checkbox'></td><td class='row'>10038</td><td class='row'>Dickson Motor Service, Inc.</td><td class='row'>Dickson Motor Service, Inc.</td><td class='row'>candlelight4u@att.net</td><td class='row'>(626) 287-9951</td><td class='row'>*</td></tr><tr id='row_1'><td><input class='input_chk' id='chkrow_1' type='checkbox'></td><td class='row'>10041</td><td class='row'>Xtreme Roadside Inc.</td><td class='row'>Xtreme Roadside Inc.</td><td class='row'>boklingel1980@gmail.com</td><td class='row'>(602) 896-1101</td><td class='row'>*</td></tr><tr id='row_2'><td><input class='input_chk'
```

Here is the link to test is http://wallahed.com/test/test.html

Comment: First things first: `cash:false,` what does that mean? Do you mean `cache` ?

Comment: When is your ajax call supposed to be done? You're not even making one.

Comment: yes sorry a mistake I mean cache

Comment: the success is when the call is done

Comment: Yes i know but where is the call?

Comment: @Daan `$("#btn").click(...)` sets the callback on the button.

Comment: I call the file.php via url: 'file.php' and the result is handled in succes function.

Comment: yes this is just to fire the call on a click

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the described behaviour on your test page. Gif animates, page is responsive, I can click the button multiple times.

Comment: Your test page seems to work for me also. Im using Chrome 36.

Comment: In Chrome the animation works but stops at the time of the table loding into the page , in firefox the animation stops and the browser is freezing at the time  of loading the table into the page. Does anyone reproduce the same issue please?

Comment: Try to generate less data with file.php, just a few rows or so.